# Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Working on a flutter app, I added the Firebase connection.
Can anyone assist me in solving this issue, please? When I'm attempting to log in, I get this error.

> Error: pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly

Comment: Please ensure that you have added correct google_services json file in project

Comment: "Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly" It looks like you have a configuration error in the database URL.